# Duplicate tables in database while building DDD

Tags: architecture, datatable, domain-driven-design

I had a discussion with an architect from my team and I want to understand do we do it all things right way.

We have several sub-domains. For instance one of them (sub-domain A) contains "Player" entity. Another one (sub-domain B) uses this entity.

For now there is two tables in database - A.Player and B.Player. B.Player contains columns needed for sub-domain B (not all A.Player, but some slice of it).

Architect telling me that this kind of architecture is pretty good for distributed system.

I think that it totally weird and will lead to duplication and inconsistency. There should be application service in sub-domaind A that provide interface for sub-domain B purposes.

The question: who is right? Where I can read information about this?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything wrong with one bounded context (BC) depending on the data from another.  I am assuming this is what you are referring to.

Just bear in mind that the data in BC-A that is used in BC-B will be a value object in BC-B.  It should only be changed in BC-A.  BC-A would be the *system of record* in this case.  The data in BC-B should *never* be changed by BC-B directly but only in response to messages from BC-A.

So the messaging is where the bit of extra effort will come into play.

Answer (score 1):

There are several options how to hanlde such a case with your "B.Player" being a ***view*** of your "A.Player". Such a view could be ***virtual*** (the information is retrieved on demand, implying some latency for queries) or ***materialized*** (the information is duplicated/stored locally, so no latency for queries, but more data managment effort instead). Data duplication will not necessarily lead to inconsistency, if properly managed. One possible approach is the master/slave pattern recommended in the answer by Eben.